# backgroundImage in CircleAvatar issue

Tags: flutter, dart

```
CircleAvatar(
        radius: 30,
        backgroundImage: fromAsset
            ? AssetImage(pic ?? '')
            : CachedNetworkImageProvider(pic ?? ''),
      ),
```

In this sampel code I have this error:
**The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type**

fromAsset : a boolian that specifies if should return circle with asset or network in this widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be solved this way:

```dart
    CircleAvatar(
       radius: 30,
       backgroundImage: fromAsset
          ? AssetImage(pic ?? '')
          : CachedNetworkImageProvider(pic ?? '') as ImageProvider,
    ),
```

In this line, a ternary operator **(? :)** is used to choose between **AssetImage** and **CachedNetworkImageProvider** based on the value of **fromAsset**. Both **AssetImage** and **CachedNetworkImageProvider** are subclasses of **ImageProvider**. However, the compiler may not always be able to automatically infer the type, so sometimes it's necessary to explicitly specify the type using casting.

By using **as ImageProvide**r, you are explicitly telling the compiler that the result of the ternary operator should be casted to the type **ImageProvider**. This is important because **backgroundImage** expects a value of type **ImageProvider**, and without explicit type indication, the compiler might issue an error if it cannot unambiguously determine the type. Casting clarifies the intended type and helps avoid potential type-related errors.

Comment: yes !it works but this 2 oyher codes work fine:
CircleAvatar(
   radius: 30,
   backgroundImage: fromAsset
      ? AssetImage(pic ?? '') as ImageProvider
      : CachedNetworkImageProvider(pic ?? '') as ImageProvider,
),

or 

CircleAvatar(
   radius: 30,
   backgroundImage: fromAsset
      ? AssetImage(pic ?? '') as ImageProvider
      : CachedNetworkImageProvider(pic ?? '') ,
),

Comment: but why cast works? why we need to use casting here?

Comment: I have added an answer to your question